# UIAlertController panel disappears before user can respond

Tags: ios, swift, controller, alert, uialertcontroller

I'm using alert controller to display error in catch block.  However, user can barely see it before it disappears by itself.  What am I doing wrong?  Here's my code.

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    if viewController is CancelInspectionViewController {
        persistentContainer.viewContext.rollback()
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        return false
    } else if viewController is SubmitInspectionViewController {
        do {
            try persistentContainer.viewContext.save()
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        } catch {
            _alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error Saving", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
            let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
            _alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
            present(_alertController, animated:true, completion: {
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that `self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` is being called in the wrong place. You are calling this as soon as you have presented _alertController. You don't actually need to call this once the alert controller is displayed. The UIAlertAction handles dismissing it.

Comment: I'm not dismissing the alert panel, I'm dismissing the tab bar controller.  However, I removed the completion block completely and the alert panel still disappears.

Comment: What if you moved this code into `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` instead. Im just wondering if the alert controller is being dismissed because you return true (after the code displayed) which then actually causes the SubmitInspectionViewController to be displayed.

Comment: I'm actually returning false.  Which is what I want because there was an error.  The submitInspectionViewController should never display, it is only there so this code will run, then I dismiss the tab bar controller.  I had this code in didSelect at one time and it didn't work there either.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! I was misunderstanding how alert controller worked.  I thought it would block the thread until user responded; it does not.  So code later in this function was dismissing the alert panel.

Working code is to return false after presenting the alert.

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    if viewController is CancelInspectionViewController {
        persistentContainer.viewContext.rollback()
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        return false
    } else if viewController is SubmitInspectionViewController {
        do {
            try persistentContainer.viewContext.save()
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        } catch {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error Saving", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
            let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
            present(alertController, animated:true, completion: nil)
            return false
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)